# Are XCTAssert/XCTFail safe in async callbacks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xctest

I have frequently seen examples where `XCTAssert` and `XCTFail` are used inside callbacks invoked while theoretically waiting for an expectation. If the timeout expires, what happens?

A contrived example (feel free to consider the equivalent in Swift, which should be the same):

```
XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"..."];

SomethingThatTakes2Seconds(^{
    XCTFail(...);
    [expectation fulfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```

In this case, we'll fail the expectation after 1 second, and then `XCTFail` will be hit a second later. Is there defined behavior? In my testing it appeared to simply be ignored, as the process ended.

However, if I piled on the tests, will a test later potentially fail nondeterministically because of the block containing `XCTFail` being invoked while it is running (assuming it is also an async test that will allow queues to run and such)?

It seems that using `__block` variables and doing all assertions in the outer test method body itself might instead be the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, `XCTFail` is just a macro that eventually expands to:

```
// XCTestAsserionsImpl.h
XCT_EXPORT void _XCTFailureHandler(XCTestCase *test, BOOL expected, const char *filePath, NSUInteger lineNumber, NSString *condition, NSString * __nullable format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(6,7);
```

So even if `XCTFail` is executed, the context (file and line number) are retained for the failure report. You won't get a surprise failure for a totally different test case's context.

Additionally, I *suspect* that when your `XCTFail` gets executed during another test case scenario that succeeds, it will not make Xcode show that test case to have failed. While I have no secret knowledge about how `_XCTFailureHandler` works internally, I often see Xcode fail to mark up test case successes and failures when I edit the test files while tests are running. Put simply, my observation led me to believe that failures are based on source code location and Xcode provides all the nice markup based on that alone -- and it can get confused when you toy around with the files.

In short, I believe (!) a delayed failure, if it is executed at all after tear down, will not affect other test cases.

I'd love to see your experiment carried out in detail, though, to verify my claim. :)

Answer (score -1):

When

```
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        ...
    }];
```

is reached test runner will pause.Test runner won't resume running until expectation is fulfilled. In this case since timeout is 1 Test will fail after waiting for 1 second.

Comment: Does not address the OP's question: will `XCTFail` calls affect other test cases when though the test case's wait limit has run up?